# sql not letting me insert 0 in the beginning

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

it work but its not adding the 0's.  When I search by name I get 35467011236 and not 0035467011236

```
Insert into dbo.AddressBook (txtphone,txtName)
VALUES
(0035467011236,'Felipe'),
(008656540,'Christopher Brown'),
(0108965490,'Mrs Roberts');
```

Comment: txtphone is `VARCHAR` ?

Comment: txtphone can't be VARCHAR since the INSERT works. (Should raise an error if trying to insert numeric data into a varchar column.)

Comment: @jarlh [Implicit conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx) do allow you to insert numerics into a VARCHAR, without an error.  If only SQL Server had it's own version of [use strict](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp).

Comment: When asking questions like this, it's extremely important to include the data types of the columns. In this case, it's the entire issue - you're most likely storing the txtphone as a numeric data type, and numeric data types (other than 0) don't have leading zeros, so expecting them to be stored with them is simply an error on your part. If you want to store text (which is what a phone number is), then store text.

Comment: @destination-data, Thanks, didn't know SQL Server allows that implicit conversion (Non-ANSI extension.)

Answer (score 4):

`0035467011236` is a number, where leading zeroes can be (will be) ignored. If you want a string (and a phonenumber is *not* a number but a string), quote it.

That `txtphone` has a varchar type, hasn't it? (it should)

Comment: If this answered your question could you [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) Hans answer.  This will help the others who follow you find the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

001 is equal to 1 for SQL numberic type column. So if you try to save data with leading zero in numeric type datatype, it will remove the leading zero.

If your requirement is to save number with leading zero, you need to change your datatype to String type (Nvarchar, Varchar)

You are saving your number without quote, that means you have taken txtnumber with numeric datatype. you must change your datatype to string type.